# It (is) sold for

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense, headlinese

I google *sold for* and see various interpretations.

> Chicago Office Tower **to Be Sold for** Record $850 Million
>
> First Wolverine Comic Art **Is Sold for** Nearly $660,000
>
> Babe Ruth's watch **sells for** $650,108
>
> Rare Velvet Underground Record **Sold for** $25k Headed Back to Auction
>
> Arrested ship **sold for** $61m

Sometimes there is an *is* but sometimes not.

What's the difference between *sold for* and *is sold for*?

Can we use *is to be sold for* instead of *to be sold for*?

Comment: I summarized "headlinese" once in this answer: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17710/3281. To summary it again, "The future is usually expressed as "to" followed by a verb." So, in headlines, you can read something "to be sold for X" as something "will be sold for X".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the "pseudo-grammar" of newspaper headlines, which effectively defy analysis

Comment: @DamkerngT.'s link is very good, and there's another good 'headlinese' answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/21490/32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titles and headlines are often not complete sentences. They don't follow all the rules of grammar. Often words are left out. Sometimes they use the present tense while a complete sentence would use other tenses.

To make these examples into complete sentences, you'd have to add a few words and sometimes shift tenses. For example:

> A Chicago office tower is being sold for a record $850 million. Or, A Chicago office tower is to be sold for a record $850 million. (If "Chicago Office Tower" is the proper name of one particular building, then it would be, "The Chicago Office Tower is ...")
>
> The first Wolverine comic art was sold for nearly $660,000.
>
> Babe Ruth's watch was sold for $650,108.

Etc.

"Is to be sold" is a somewhat complex construction, but it usually means the same as "will be sold".

Answer (score 1):

**Sold for…** might be an header or an article title while **is sold for…** is a complete sentence.

**Is to be sold** is roughly equivalent to **it has to be sold**.

First construction is more formal and more general while the second is more common and more specific.

Is to be sold implies a desirable or expected state while to be sold expresses that something is available for sale.