# Meaning of "somebody/something to verb"

Tags: verb-forms, headlinese

I saw an article starts with: "A company to launch a new product", in a news paper.
I just wonder what does it mean?  Is it a kind of usage of near future? (e.g. is to do something)

Comment: This is [***headlinese***](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17710/32), an artificial syntax contrived to minimize the length of headlines. The sense is, as you perceive, *[Company] **is** to launch a new product*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @StoneyB indicated, it's headlinese. Here's a general reference: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+headlinese

You can transform it into standard English one of two ways, "is to" or "is going to". The former is more formal or used in specialized situations.

1. Apple **to** launch new iPhone in 2014(Headlinese)
2. Apple **is to** launch a new iPhone in 2014. (Formal or stylized. Announcement.)
3. Apple **is going to** launch a new iPhone in 2014. (Standard English.)

One would choose between #2 or #3 for stylistic reasons.  Of course, some style guides would mandate #2.  Also, in a tight business presentation, one may prefer to use the shorter form (#2).  On the other hand, if one didn't want to sound so strict and official, they could use #3 even in an otherwise formal setting.

---

**Related Info:**  To round-out this answer with some closely related grammatical structures, consider the following sentences:

- Mary is going to the store. (A simple declarative statement.)
- Mary is to the store.* (Doesn't work.)
- Mary is to go to the store. (A declaration of a command.)
- Mary is to leave the store. (A declaration of a command.)
- Mary is going to leave the store. (A declaration of something as a fact, especially if spoken to someone and Mary isn't listening.)
- Mary is going to leave the store, now. (If said sternly in front of others, including Mary, this is rhetorically letting both others and Mary of the speaker's desire.)