# question about' 'noun +past participle'

Tags: grammar, headlinese

When I watch movies, I usually hear one person say to another a short phrase with the structure "noun + past participle" in the conversation. Here's two examples:

> "Request denied."
>
> "Permission approved."

I can understand that they mean "I deny your request" and "I approve your permission." I often see such a sentence structure in news headlines such as: "Woman killed in the conflict" or "Child found in an empty house", but seldom see such usage in spoken English. If this usage is correct, can I say "two pairs of shoes wanted" to a salesman when I visit a shop?

Comment: It's easy to confuse [Headlinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) with normal English. I believe that you got those phrases from headlines. (I wrote about it once [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17710/3281). You can search for "headlinese" to check out other ELL posts.) In reality, this matter is a little bit more complicated because English also has postmodifiers (e.g. *"If you have the book mentioned above, you can find the quote on page 42."*)

Answer (score 1):

> if it can be used like that, can i say ' two pairs of shoes wanted' to
>   the salesman when i visit the shop??

If one uses such an expression in speech (e.g. "complaint noted", "point taken") the brevity of the locution can connote either a sort of (bureaucratic?) distancing of the speaker from the issue at hand, the opposite of empathy, or perhaps a willingness on the part of the speaker to treat the issue seriously. But it marks a departure from the normal conversational register.

You would not say to a shop clerk, "two pairs of shoes wanted". But you might put that on a public bulletin board:  "Ride wanted".  There it's close to headlinese.  Deliberate brevity because of limited space.