# Lack of indefinite articles on webpages

Tags: articles, headlinese

According to the tab on the right I can **ask question**.

But we would never say that. I can **ask a question**. However, *question* is neither an an abstract nor uncountable noun.

I also noticed the same rule in an online system I use - I can **add order**.

Are these phrases incorrect or is it a rule that justifies omitting the articles?

Comment: This is [tag:headlinese], a style of writing used in headlines, captions, signs, labels and similar situations where little space is available. There's a very good description of headlinese in the accepted answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/17672/32).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not a formal communication, there is no **hard and fast rule** on how it should be done.  It probably falls into the same category as **advertising copy**: **short**, **punchy**, **to-the-point**, since the user's **attention span** will be less than a goldfish's.

A few other things going on here:

**The Text**
With or without the **a**, **Ask Question** is perfectly understandable in what will happen if you click on it. This falls under the **less-is-more** category.

**The Layout**
 The other possibilities: **Questions** and **Unanswered** are also available at this level of the **menu hierarchy**. **Ask question** is about the same size as **Unanswered** and the designer may have felt this was good.  Only using **Ask** might be considered too short/small in comparison to other choices on that line. If **Ask Question** ws too short, one may expect the designer to do something to make it look the same as the others. The texts that are used are **label_tags** which acts as a clickable button, so keeping them the same size is good practice.

Comment: How can it be informal communication if it is a website of a company or Stack Exchange?

Comment: Formal communication usually has a **stiffness** about it interms of language and phrasing, in the extreme think of legal documents. Websites tend to want to be **accessible** and so will appear more **casual** and **colloquial**. Postings on ELL, need to be **correct**, but do not need to be **formal**. We do not start every question with **To Whomever May Be Interested**, but then again we don't write **How'dy y'all** *(at least I've never seen it)*