# After being struck and dies vs died

Tags: grammar

Here are some sentences about 'after being'

> 1. Schoolgirl awarded €20,000 after being locked in classroom.

http://www.irishtimes.com/news/crime-and-law/courts/circuit-court/schoolgirl-awarded-20-000-after-being-locked-in-classroom-1.2842852

> 2. Girl dies after being struck by lightning.

http://kathmandupost.ekantipur.com/news/2016-06-08/girl-dies-after-being-struck-by-lightning.html

> 3. Two people die after being swept away by river.

http://kathmandupost.ekantipur.com/news/2016-09-21/two-die-after-being-swept-away-by-river.html

I think we can use 'after being+past participle' when one action immediately follows another action. For example: Girl dies after being struck by lightning.

Here, It means: Girl dies after she was struck by lightning.

Am I correct?

I think I can change 'dies' into 'died'.

For example:

> Girl died after being struck by lightning.

Why has 'Girl dies' been written in the news even if she died in past?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences in meaning when the verb tense changes (headlines)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/differences-in-meaning-when-the-verb-tense-changes-headlines) And [Understanding the simple present use when reporting past events](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73673/), which was closed as a duplicate of the former (there will be others, I'm sure).

Comment: What about my 1st question?

Comment: You're only supposed to as *one* question in a post. And given your "first" question asks about the validity of *Girl dies after she was struck by lightning*, which could ***only*** occur in a "headlinese" context (trust me, no native speakers actually *speak* like that) it seems fair to choose the latter for a dup closevote. There are probably also duplicates asking about exactly how ***after*** can be used, but you haven't set out very clearly what you're asking there.

Answer (score 3):

News headlines like to describe things in present tense to make them more exciting and interesting to readers.

See [this English stack exchange answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117100/why-are-news-headlines-in-present-tense-if-they-refer-to-past-events)

**EDIT**

Yes, you are correct about the meaning of "after being". "Girl dies after being struck by lightening" is the same as "Girl dies after she was struck by lightening".

Comment: And what about my first question?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Ok, I upvoted your answer