# What does the 'to' mean when the word is used in the newspaper?

Tags: meaning, headlinese

I saw the sentence like 'The president to agree with the opinion.'in the news paper.
I can understand the meaning of the 'to' in the sentence.
Maybe I think that 'to' means 'will'.
Am I right?
If I am wrong, What is the right meaning of 'to' in the sentence?
Please, tell me.

Comment: See Damkerng T answer here http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/differences-in-meaning-when-the-verb-tense-changes-headlines

Answer (score 6):

Newspaper headlines by their very nature are designed to grab as much attention as possible, in the least possible space, and as such, almost have a [grammar of their own](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/8-grammar-rules-writing-newspaper-headlines/).

One example of this is the use of the infinitive form of the verb to refer to future events - e.g.

> Parliament **to decide** new policy tomorrow.
>
> Germany **to take in** 5000 more refugees.
>
> President **to visit** France for further talks.

Using the infinitive in this manner, a future time is not always necessary to demonstrate the future tense in headlines.

In your example:

> The president **to agree** with the opinion.

...simply means that the president will agree with this opinion, sometime in the future.

On a related note, I'm presuming your example is one you made up for the purposes of the question, as it doesn't seem to be as concise as one would expect form a headline. *President to agree with reforms* or similar would be more realistic.