# what is the "ordered" of "De Lima ordered arrested by RTC" in news headline

Tags: syntax, headlinese

> De Lima **ordered** arrested by RTC [link](http://news.abs-cbn.com/news/02/23/17/de-lima-ordered-arrested-by-rtc)

From this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/differences-in-meaning-when-the-verb-tense-changes-headlines)

I somewhat understand of Headlinese. However, I still don't understand *ordered*. I mean, I can understand *was* is omitted in following sentence.

> De Lima (*was*) arrested by RTC

But in the sentence, two past participles are arranged side by side. I tried to study Headlinese but I couldn't find answer clearly.

Could somebody make a perfect(normal) sentence from the headline? I read someone said it can be various cases. Then could you make some sentences which is possible to suppose.

So far, my best attempt is that

> De Lima *(was)* ordered *(to be)* arrested by RTC

I'm not sure, though.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: RTC ordered someone to arrest De Lima. It's just a passive voice version of that.

Comment: To clarify further, *from the headline ALONE*, we do not know if De Lima was arrested, only that the order to arrest him was sent. Therefore both your suggestions are not implied in the headline.

Answer (score 3):

Macmillan provides many definitions of *order* as a verb; two of them are:

> ▸ to ask for a product to be made for you or delivered to you
>   ▸ to tell someone to do something

So, if I say:

> Bob ordered a cake

that means Bob went to the bakery and asked for a cake to be made, but if I say:

> Bob ordered arrested by police chief

This time, the police chief is doing the ordering, and it's a different kind of order. The chief is telling his police force to make the arrest.

Another way to say this would be:

> Police Chief orders that Bob be arrested

So, in your sentence:

> De Lima ordered arrested by RTC

That means: the RTC issued an order for DeLima's arrest

Comment: How "issued an order" can be "ordered"?