# Is "All rights reserved" correct?

Tags: grammar

I think it is wrong because it should be in passive voice, so "All rights are reserved" is correct. Is it that people are too lazy to make a change even they realize there is a mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences in meaning when the verb tense changes (headlines)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/differences-in-meaning-when-the-verb-tense-changes-headlines)

Comment: So you think millions of native speakers, including lawyers, are writing something that is wrong because they're too lazy to change it?  Did you look up "all rights reserved"?  What did you find about the usage?

Comment: In many situations (for example road signs, slogans, warning labels, headlines, etc) the syntax is simplified for the sake of brevity.  "Keep Away From Children" omits "this product".  It does not mean to avoid children.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also think when someone wishes you "Happy birthday!" it's also because they're too "lazy" to say the full sentence, "I hope you have a happy birthday"?

I'm sure your own native language has many "standard phrases", which are well-known *abbreviations* of longer expressions.  "All Rights Reserved" is one such in English, or (as Tᴚoɯɐuo mentions in his comment) "Keep Away From Children", or "No Smoking", "Fire Hazard", "Batteries Not Included", "Some Assembly Required", "This End Up", "Handle With Care", or even the ubiquitous "Good Morning".

As with any language, the basic grammar is just there to get you started.  Once you learn that, you need to learn how English is actually *used* by native speakers.

Comment: but there are some examples of errors being accepted as normal in English, such as "Long time no see". I think when people choose to abbreviate, they want to save time and trouble, but "All rights are reserved" and "All rights reserved" do not make much difference.

Comment: @NanningYouth there are perhaps thousands of such phrases in English.  You might as well get used to them.