# Usage and meaning of "to" before a verb

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Theresa May **to** press Trump at G7 to reverse metal tariffs .

Link to this news was [Here](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/jun/02/theresa-may-trump-g7-reverse-european-steel-aluminium-tariffs)

The first "to" is vague for me but second "to" would mean "in the means of".
So, I would be glad for some help !

Comment: It's a common way to refer to a [future event in headlines](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/differences-in-meaning-when-the-verb-tense-changes-headlines/17710#17710).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that it is an stylistic resource used by journalists.

[Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) [wikipedia]

> Headlinese is an abbreviated form of news writing style used in
>   newspaper headlines. Because space is limited, headlines are
>   written in a compressed telegraphic style, using special syntactic
>   conventions, including:
>
> ...
>
> - Most verbs are in the simple present tense, e.g. "Governor signs
>     bill", **while the future is expressed by an infinitive, with to
>     followed by a verb**, as in "Governor to sign bill".

In your case

> Theresa May (is going) **to** press Trump at G7 to reverse metal tariffs .

Comment: Is it acceptable using such style out of news ?( because I'm not journalist!)

Comment: @Abbas It's not gramatically correct. It may be used to ressemble that style in literature.

Comment: There's some style in literature which is gramatically wrong?

Comment: @Abbas If a novel's main character is a journalist, he's thoughts may be shown as headlines, for example. And poetry does not follow grammatical rules always. That's what I mean.